# How to count how many times a number occurs in each column of a file?

Tags: bash, text-processing, python

I have a txt file containing a list of negative numbers and a csv file containing numbers in 3 columns. All the number in the csv file is included in the txt file and the txt file contains only numbers that are present in the csv file.

Here is a short example:

```
cat list.txt
-14.5
-12.3
-10.1
-10.0
-9.9
-9.8
-7.3
-0.1

cat numbers.csv
-14.5,-14.5,-12.3
-14.5,-12.3,-10.1
-10.0,-9.9,-10.1
-7.3,-9.8,-10.1
-7.3,-7.3,-10.1
-0.1,-0.1,-9.8
```

I need to know how many times each number in `list.txt` occurs in each column of `numbers.csv`.

In the example above, the expected result should be:

```
-14.5: 2,1,0
-12.3: 0,1,1
-10.1: 0,0,4
-10.0: 1,0,0
-9.9: 0,1,0
-9.8: 0,1,1
-7.3: 2,1,0
-0.1: 1,1,0
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I am a very beginner in bash and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the first file into an array.
2. For each line: Compare each column to all number array members and increment the counting array entry for each match.
3. After processing all lines: Print all members of the number array with the column counts.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR { n[NR]=$1; count=NR; next; }; '\
'{ for(i=1;i<=count;i++) { number=n[i]; '\
'  if (number==$1) c[number,1]++; '\
'  if (number==$2) c[number,2]++; '\
'  if (number==$3) c[number,3]++;  } }; '\
'END { for(i=1;i<=count;i++) { number=n[i]; text=number ": "; '\
'for(col=1;col<4;col++) { if (c[number,col]=="") c[number,col]=0; if (col>1) text=text ","; '\
'text=text c[number,col];} print text; }; }' list.txt numbers.csv 

-14.5: 2,1,0
-12.3: 0,1,1
-10.1: 0,0,4
-10.0: 1,0,0
-9.9: 0,1,0
-9.8: 0,1,1
-7.3: 2,1,0
-0.1: 1,1,0
```